# How to know the statistics are up to date in Oracle Database?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, database-performance, sql-tuning

How to know the statistics are up to date, is there any way to find when the last statistics were calculated?

Do I need to just look at the stale_stats and last_analyzed column of the dba_tab_statistics view?

Comment: Yes that's the usual way to proceed (`last_analyzed` can also be found in `all_tables`). Are you disatisfied with the information that you are seeing in there?

Comment: I'm not sure whether it is the only way or not. @GMB

Comment: Since this is tagged 12c, unless you've changed the default configuration, Oracle has a job that automatically gathers statistics overnight on any tables it judges to have stale statistics.  Unless you have tables whose usage patterns don't work with that job (i.e. a staging table that is empty overnight when stats are gathered that gets loaded with millions of rows as part of a daytime ETL run), you probably don't need to be overly concerned with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find this in the `XXX_TABLES` views (e.g. DBA_TABLES, USER_TABLES, ALL_TABLES). The column you're looking for is LAST_ANALYZED, so for example

```
SELECT OWNER, TABLE_NAME, LAST_ANALYZED
  FROM USER_TABLES
```

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6ed5ca59268d9896a37504a3d55680f6)

Comment: `OWNER`  is not a column in the `USER_TABLES` view. Otherwise +1, thanks!